# how to install packages in sublime text editor 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have installed package control in sublime text editor 3 build 3114. When I try to install new packages/plugins they not installed. Nothing shows any message.Please tell me how to install packages/plugins?

Comment: Do none of these questions help you? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sublime+install+package+control

Answer (score 7):

To install a package in ST2 and ST3, you first need to correctly install the correct version of Package Control (there is one version for ST2 and another one for ST3, see the [Package Control installation page](http://packagecontrol.io/installation)).

Once you've successfully completed the instalation (you can detect any error message in the status bar), you can start managing package via the Command Palette (`Ctrl + Shift + P` on Windows, then type `Install package`, then chose any package and press Enter). A confirmation message should appear in the status bar.

If you follow each of these steps, everything should work properly. Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I have installed official package controller and now I have copy code in console and now it is working code is given in package controller Installation page.

Comment: Ok, your problem is definitely solved then ? Or do you need anymore help ?

Comment: Just one more please correct that in windows is ctrl+shift+p

Comment: Done, I had written `Maj` because I have a french keyboard. Have you finally managed to install the package ?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) you can do this in your home directory.
$ cd .config/sublime-text-3/Packages
clone git repo for the package like this
ex: (git clone https://github.com/braver/TypeScriptSyntax.git)
$ git clone package repo url
that's it then close your sublime and restart sublime.

now if you do ctrl+shift+p then type typesript you should able to see the 
package and use to set the syntax.